# JavaScript How to access a variable from an object passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a probably really simple problem, but I can't figure it out. I'll post some cut snippets of the code that doesn't work for some reason:

```
//authentication_handler.js
var new_user = server.authenticated_users.add_user(new User(world));

//user.js
function User(world) {
personBody = createPlayerBody(100, 100, 8, 8, false, true, world);
exports.TheBody = personBody;
}

//player_data_handler.js
module.exports = function(server, client) {
var theUser = server.authenticated_users.find_user(client.uuid);
if (theUser != null) {
    var playerData = JSON.stringify({
        x: theUser.TheBody.position.x, //this line throws the error below
        y: theUser.TheBody.position.y
    });
    server.authenticated_users.each_other(theUser, function(user) {
        server.send_id_message(user.client, 5, playerData);
    });
}
};
```

The error I get is this:

> Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

I'm still pretty new to JavaScript and I don't know why the "personBody" variable doesn't get passed all the way to the "player_data_handler.js". I've tried more approaches but none of them worked. Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exports` is used for exporting parts of a module.  If you want to add something to your object, use `this`:

Instead of `exports.TheBody = personBody;` try `this.TheBody = personBody;`

Comment: `exports` is not an instance of `User`, which the OP is trying to give the property `TheBody`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don;t see how `new User()` has relation with `module.exports`. can you elaborate ? of course setting `this.TheBody` with value , will cause any instance of `new USer()` to has a public property called TheBody , but where module.export comes into the story ?